# How to get the list of keys an `operator.itemgetter` was created with?

Tags: python

I have an `operator.itemgetter()` object, e.g.

```
import operator
keyfunc = operator.itemgetter("key1", "key2")
```

Now, I pass it around and later I wish to get the list of keys it was created with, e.g.

```
# doesn't exist, but should return something like ("key1", "key2")
keys = keyfunc.keys()
```

The object stores the keys obviously for use with `__call__`, and it also prints them:

```
>>> print(keyfunc)
operator.itemgetter('key1', 'key2')
```

But I don't spot a member that might return those keys in the output of `dir(keyfunc)`. The documentation also doesn't list an accessor for this query either.

Do I need to parse the output of the string representation (or store and pass the keys alongside the object)?

```
# this feels a bit hacky
import ast
keys = ast.literal_eval(repr(keyfunc).replace("operator.itemgetter", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/operator.py):

```
class itemgetter:
    __slots__ = ('_items', '_call')
    
    def __init__(self, item, *items):
        if not items:
            self._items = (item,)
```

So, the keys are stored in `_items` attribute. however, when you try to access it, you get an `AttributeError`:

```
>>> a._items
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'operator.itemgetter' object has no attribute '_items'
```

So, reading the source code a little bit more, we see that dunder method `__reduce__` is defined in the class, so you can use it:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    return self.__class__, self._items

  >>> a.__reduce__()
(<class 'operator.itemgetter'>, ('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: Not sure if this is public API, but it seems to work at least (`keys = keyfunc.__reduce__()[1]`). Thanks!

Comment: For sure this is also an ugly hack and not an intended use of the `__reduce__` method. Use at your own discretion :)

Comment: You linked to the Python source code. I think the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b27b57c6e44a276c8a9843fd37d4cf65b2827d5c/Modules/_operator.c#L971) is what actually ends up being used.

Comment: Might as well be, that'll explain the `AttributeError`

Answer (score 0):

Another hack: Use it on a dummy object that tracks what the itemgetter asks for:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(bool)
keyfunc(d)
print(list(d))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xCgIxEET7fEW4KgER1MbGjzmTjS4m2bA3V9zX5yKoWA1vBt60DU@pl2vT3rk0UVhppDNEzYu2tNZgb7/qyKDyIIDUTWM@TQf7zvPkjUkqxQbJmQJY6mI/vkhpXjMiB5g4ZH/s7iLZf49c9KYpV7jMCwb53nc)):

```
['key1', 'key2']
```

This assumes that you're not using duplicate keys, that the keys are hashable, and that itemgetter asks for the keys in the original order.

Another, which can handle duplicate and unhashable keys:

```
def itemgetter_keys(ig):
    keys = []
    class C:
        __getitem__ = keys.append
    ig(C())
    return keys

print(itemgetter_keys(keyfunc))
```

Same output `['key1', 'key2']` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7NCsIwDL73KcpOLchAvYjgaY8hUsqW1aJrQ5od9vS1raJgLsn3lwQ3vsdwPCHl7BeMxDIikOVI4gHbvIZRXr5U7xkWB8xAqivyvtvJ2g@dFmKCWf50U@ikvNNnIUtVVBZdbw2NT5uSHN5SLWNKqoaNKa5q7i0ihKk5vFOD0rrNBLxSaBYhkHxg9X/087fWOb8A)).